# Do you need to be specific about a file location when using os or do you still ned to write (folder/file)?

Tags: file, operating-system

Let's say I have a file called hello.txt in the folder called coding, and I want to open that in python. I know that if I don't use `os`, I would have to write `open("coding/hello.txt")` but if I would write `os.open` would I still have to specify the folder like `("coding/hello.txt")` or can I just write `os.open("hello.txt")` because I am using `os`?

Answer (score 1):

"File" and "operating system" can mean a lot of different things, but typically operating systems have the concept of a "current" or "working" directory. Each process has its own current directory, and if you don't specify a directory for a file it uses the current directory.

Do not rely on this. Too many things can change the current directory unexpectedly, and your program will suddenly start using a different file.

Instead always specify the full file path like `open("/usr/tmp/coding/hello.txt")` or whatever is appropriate for your operating system; it will probably provide environment variables or something for the user's home or temporary directories.

Note that your examples `"coding/hello.txt"` and `"hello.txt"` both use the current directory, and are different files.

Comment: Thank you! So basically it would work but avoid it just in case?

Comment: No, avoid current directories because you don't know if it will work or not